# Ansible default value and split string

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am trying to set a default value in ansible script and if the variable is present would like to split the substring?
assuming if `env_var: 10.6.1` is then I want to `set some_var1 to 10.6 or default to 10.5`

I know we can set the default value but not sure how to extract substring if the env variable is present

```
some_var1 : "{{ env_var | default(10.5) }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you could just do:

```
some_var_1: "{{ '.'.join((env_var | default('10.5')).split('.')[:2]) }}"
```

This will take the value of `env_var` (or the string '10.5' if that variable is not available), split it in `.`, and then join the first two components using `.`.

Answer (score 0):

Take the first item of [splitext](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id8)

```
some_var1: "{{ env_var | default('10.5.0')|splitext|first }}"
```